# Set option for select Jquery

Tags: jquery

I am using the following lines to select the value of an option for a select menu element.

```
var chap = $("#xyz).val();
$('#qEchap').val(chap);
```

or

```
var chap = $("#xyz).val();
$('#qEchap option[value=chap]').attr("selected", "selected");
```

Both are not working. What is the right syntax to set option value for a HTML select menu?

Comment: [What Do You Mean “It Doesn’t Work”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/147616/289905) Where’s your HTML? There’s an obvious syntax error there: you’re missing a `"` in each code block in this post. Please post a [mre]. The problem could be anything, e.g. [Why does jQuery or a DOM method such as `getElementById` not find the element?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14028959/4642212), or a typo, or something else.

Comment: Tell me one language that uses this as correct syntax. ("#xyz)

Comment: sorry guys for all the confusion.. the code was too long and I could not paste everything ... the real issue was there was an Ajax call that was overwriting this statement... I moved this code within success of Ajax and it worked

Answer (score 1):

Hope you read jQuery docs carefully to get acquainted with syntaxes.

```
var chap = $("#xyz").val();
$('#qEchap').val(chap);
```

---

```
var chap = $("#xyz").val();
$('#qEchap option[value=chap]').attr("selected", true);
```